# Fiware stack iotagent,Orion context broker compatibility with AWS DocumentDB instead of mongoDB

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Can anybody confirm the AWS DocumentDB compatibility with Fiware GE's like iotagent,Orion context broker.
Is fiware stack fully working with DocumentDB. Looking for a suggestions and things to be consider before attempting it.

Thanks
ONR

Answer (score 1):

Since AWS DocumentDB only supports a subset of MongoDB, there is definitely going to be some incompatibility.

Take for example geoqueries:

```
curl -G -X GET \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities' \
  -d 'type=Store' \
  -d 'georel=near;maxDistance:1500' \
  -d 'geometry=point' \
  -d 'coords=52.5162,13.3777'
```

Internally these rely on the MongoDB geospatial operations which are not currently supported: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-geospatial

In my understanding, the IoT Agents are just using Mongo-DB as a simple memory store for mapping data so would not have any issues.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your quick and valuable information!. Any further view points and limitations we would like to know from the forum who has experimented or tried with AWS DocumentDB instead of MongoDB.