# Fiware Orion Broker and Database Connectivity

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We are using MongoDB for our on-premise environment.

1. When would Orion officially support AWS DocumentDB
2. Would Orion drop MongoDB after supporting DocumentDb or support both in future.

These questions came up after seeing the few related discussion.
Is Orion compatible with AWS DocumentDB #3778
https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3778

[Fiware stack iotagent,Orion context broker compatibility with AWS DocumentDB instead of mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842042/fiware-stack-iotagent-orion-context-broker-compatibility-with-aws-documentdb-ins)

Geospatial - Geometry Specifiers
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-geospatial

**Updated Query**

1. What software stack (set of components, environment) is officially supported by FIWARE community?
   -> Orion v3.0.0 should use Mongo 4.4 with CentOS 8 on x86_64?
2. Does Orion v3.0.0 officially support using AWS DocumentDB as a backend DB except for some known limitations such as geoqueries.

Answer (score 1):

We took a quick look at DocumentDB and if I'm not wrong, there is no support for geoqueries, thus not really interesting for Orion/Orion-LD. And no, I strongly doubt we'd drop mongo, both would most probably be supported simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, AWS Document DB is a kind of clone of the official MongoDB software. Taking into account the fixes done [in the context the issue you cite](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3778) it should be supported since Orion 3.0.0 (maybe with some limitations, as the geo-queries that @kzangeli mentions). If you have evidences on the contraty, please publish them as comment in [that issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3778).

Orion will not drop support of MongoDB in favour of any of their un-official clones.

**EDIT:**

> What software stack (set of components, environment) is officially supported by FIWARE community? -> Orion v3.0.0 should use Mongo 4.4 with CentOS 8 on x86_64?

That's correct with regards to Orion. As alternative, you can also use docker-based deployment, so you could use any (hosting) operating system able to run docker containers.

> Does Orion v3.0.0 officially support using AWS DocumentDB as a backend DB except for some known limitations such as geoqueries.

No. The only DB officially supported by Orion is MongoDB. However, the lack of official support doesn't means no support at all ;). You are encourage to test and tell us how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Few more queries added to the question, Please answer.

Comment: My post has been edited to include some additional answers.